# Create new instance of a given object, using same arguments provided in __init__

Tags: python-3.x, class, object, iterator, instance

Given any iterator, I want to be able to pass this iterator into my function, to return a new iter object that cycles through the given iter infinitely. E.G

```
class range:
    def __init__(self, min, max, step):
        self.min = min
        self.max = max
        self.step = counter
        [...] other vars

    def __next__(self):
        if [.............]
```

You get the jist. I have a bunch of custom iterators like this, all created with diff args/params. I know I can use vars to get the variables... but how do you distinguish between vars passed into init to create this object, and others vars? Vars returnsmin/max/counter + all the other vars

I have a class like this:

```
class Cycle:

    def __init__(self, iterable):
        self.iterable = iterable

    def __next__(self):
        next_val = next(self.iterable, None)
        if next_val is None:
            #RESET iterable or create new instance of iterable with same _init_ args used to create it
            next_val = next(self.iterable)
        return next_val
```

Intended use:

r = range(0,4,2)
next(r) = 0

next(r) = 2

next(r) = 4

next(r) = stopiterationerror

c = Cycle(r)

next(c) = 0

next(c) = 2

next(c) = 4

next(c) = 0

next(c) = 2

next(c) = 4

.......
I want to keep this cycle function clean and simple if I can. Ideally I would want to simply self.iterable.reset, but it seems like resetting an iterable is not possible in python and I need to create a brand new instance. I know I could pass in *args into cycle, but is it possible to avoid that?

edit currently working:

```
class Cycle:

    def __init__(self, iterable):
        self.iterable = iterable
        self.copy = copy(iterable)

    def __next__(self):
        next_val = next(self.iterable, None)
        if next_val is None:
            self.iterable = self.copy
            self.copy = copy(self.copy)
            next_val = next(self.iterable, None)
        return next_val
```

Comment: The object keeps no record of the arguments that were passed to `__init__`, if you want that, then you need to implement that. But I really don't understand your use-case. I suspect there i a better overall design/solution

Comment: IOW there is no way to accomplish this generically. The way `itertools` solves this in `cycle` is by creating a list as it iterates and cycling through that list when the iterator is exhausted

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I just want an iterator that takes any iterable object and essentially returns an infinite cycle of the passed in iterator. It's for a programming assignment/take home/interview type exercise. I didn't think it would be this tricky, but it seems to me, conceptually, that recreating a new instance of the iterable passed in would be the best solution. Otherwise, if you're given a generator that generates a million numbers, and you use the itertools.cycle approach, you are storing a million numbers in memory. Unless you see a diff approach to solving this.

Comment: I already explained to you, that isn't possible *in general*. In fact, the way `itertools.cycle` from the python standard library does it [is by saving the already seen elements in a list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle). Now, if you are working only with your own *custom* iterators/iterables, then you can do something

Comment: I'm not sure why you explained how itertools.cycle works again, I've already mentioned it above as a possible approach, and the limitations of that approach (i know how it works).

Comment: Yes, and I already explained to you why trying to avoid this is not really possible in general - there is no generic way to "reset" an iterator . I am pointing out that the standard library does it in a particular way to maybe try to convince you that very smart, experienced developers who have intimate knowledge of the language have not found a better way.

Comment: What isn't exactly clear to me is if you want this to work with **any iterator** or any one of your *custom* iterators. If the latter, then you can add such a re-set functionality to your custom iterators. (or perhaps, a "copy original state" function)

Comment: Requirements are straightforward.  Given **any iterator**, wrap/pass it in a cycle iterator to allow the given iterator to cycle through its contents indefinitely. I think the only two solutions are copy given object-> when .next is None, copy the copy, so there will be 2 copies + original before the next .next call, OR store all results and loop through results. I know not recommended, but I have read eval(repr(obj)) would be able to store an object state and instantiate a new one, but have not gotten that to work. I know it is not recommended to use in this way.

Comment: "but I have read eval(repr(obj)) would be able to store an object state and instantiate a new one," No. No that isn't true, and that isn't going to give you any different information other than a potentially less informative and unwieldy (since its is a *string*) version of `vars(obj)` -- although, it isn't guaranteed to give you **anything** informative. Anyone is free to implement `__repr__` however they want as long as it returns *some `str`*

Comment: I am not sure why you cannot accept the fact that what you want to do isn't possible in the general case without auxiliary storage. Now, you could use `initial_state = vars(obj).copy()` to get a dictionary representing the state of the object, but there is no way to know what arguments were passed to the constructor of an object. You could try to use `initial_state` to reconstruct the object, if it is indeed an object with a `__dict__`, then simply `new_instance = object.__new__(type(obj)); vars(new_instance).update(initial_state)` but this will not work in general

Comment: I appreciate your help and your suggestions. I can definitely accept it, I'm just trying to figure out the limitations of python and the best solution to a simple requirement with complex implications. This is what I have now, will try your suggestion right now as well. The shallow copy works for infinite cycling.

Comment: ```class Cycle:

    def __init__(self, iterable):

        self.iterable = iterable

        self.copy = copy(iterable)



    def __next__(self):

        next_val = next(self.iterable, None)

        if next_val is None:

            self.iterable = self.copy

            self.copy = copy(self.copy)

            next_val = next(self.iterable, None)

        return next_val```

Comment: Suppose you have an object, `sensor = HeatSensor()` which reads from a device that gives you second-by-second temperature readings. Copying that object and cycling through it isn't going to work, because iterating over a copy will give you *new temperature readings*.  Fundamentally, the *only* way to do this is by keeping track of the values produced by iteration. This is why `itertools.cycle` does it that way. But perhaps for your purposes simpy copying `iterable` could work

Comment: But just consider if `iterable` is a generator, it won't work! You can't copy generators. And that is a pretty important category of iterators

Comment: You are right! Thanks for telling me that! I didn't know you can't clone generators. Getting an error with that. Good catch man! Thank you.

```TypeError: cannot pickle 'generator' object```

I just wanted to be theory with my solution instead of copy pasting itertools. Appreciate the discussion. I guess that's the best method.